# unordered list items not aligning to each other

Tags: html, css, list, navigation, header

I have this code that should create a sticky navigation bar on the top of the site:

```
#navigation-bar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: rgb(225, 151, 77, 0.95);
    overflow: hidden;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

#navigation-bar li {
    float: left;
}

#navigation-bar li a {
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#navigation-bar li a:hover {
    background-color: red;
    color: rgb(225, 151, 77);
}

header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

#navigation-home-logo {
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}


<header>
    <nav>
        <ul id="navigation-bar">
            <li><a href=""><img  id="navigation-home-logo" src=""></a></li>
            <li><a href="">INSTAGRAM</a></li>
            <li><a href="">TIKTOK</a></li>
            <li><a href="">TWITTER</a></li>
            <li><a href="">YOUTUBE</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

I don't understand why the other links are not lining vertically with the image, I tried setting the image padding and margin to 0 but obv it didn't work and I have no idea of what the problem is
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because that's how `display: block` works, you can use Flex in order to do so. Like:

```css
#navigation-bar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: rgb(225, 151, 77, 0.95);
    overflow: hidden;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

#navigation-bar li {
    float: left;
}

#navigation-bar li a {
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#navigation-bar li a:hover {
    background-color: red;
    color: rgb(225, 151, 77);
}

header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

#navigation-home-logo {
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul id="navigation-bar">
            <li><a href=""><img  id="navigation-home-logo" src="https://picsum.photos/200"></a></li>
            <li><a href="">INSTAGRAM</a></li>
            <li><a href="">TIKTOK</a></li>
            <li><a href="">TWITTER</a></li>
            <li><a href="">YOUTUBE</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Works great! Thx man

Comment: Actually there is one thing, before applying your change when i went over an item with the mouse the whole item would change its attributes to the ones in a:hover but now only the text area changes, the orange part outside of it remains the same

Comment: Okay, so, actually before my change it was the same, you think as "the whole item" and "text area" but actually, it is just the `<a>` tag, the hover changes the a background, and what you see that is not changed is actually its parent `<li>` . So in order to do so, change the parent background when hover and give it the desired height also using flex:
`#navigation-bar li {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
 align-items:center;
}

#navigation-bar li:hover {
    background-color: red;
    color: rgb(225, 151, 77);
}`

Wrong formatting, Ill edit the answer

Comment: Yeah i figured out it was changing only the a tag, thx for the answer btww

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use display:block in the nav element instead of the specific links, because display block is applied to all elements inside the element you're applying it to:

```
nav{
    display: block;
}
```